# Filter from the same user times

Tags: mysql

i have a table with user id-s, and many times for the same users, like this:

```
id    time
1     13:00:01
1     13:00:01
2     13:00:09
1     13:00.23
1     13:00:24
2     13:00:11
2     13:00:11
```

I would like to get this dataset:

```
id    time
1     13:00:01
2     13:00:09
1     13:00.23
2     13:00:11
```

So i would like remove all the rows with the same id-time pair and with the same id, but where the time between the same user times is bigger than 20s. Can anybody help to me? I'm hanging on this problem for 4 days :(

Comment: you could try to group by user_id and time divided by 20s (simplest when represented as timestamp)

Comment: tried to show it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7030a/2 but in your expected results those two rows for id=2 do differ by only 2 seconds, not 20, so it groups them together

Comment: Very nice solution, thank you. I tried with my real data. The most of was good, but i found one, where was error. I pasted to the fiddle. Can you see it?

Comment: insert into times values
(1,'23:32:16'),
(1,'23:45:42'),
(1,'23:58:39'),
(1,'00:12:10'),
(1,'23:32:16'),
(1,'23:45:43'),
(1,'23:58:40'),
(1,'00:12:11');

And the last 2 result is closer than 20s. 23:58:39 and 23:58:40

Comment: @user1786423 : if i set diff from 20 to 50, it is good. I don't understand.

Comment: Ah, yes, this does not work then :( those two are each in different "group" and each group consists of 20 seconds (multiples of 20).. You want it from "first" to group all less, that will be harder, it would usually use window functions, but these are not available in mysql.

Comment: :( In this case there are no possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c88a4/8

```
select t1.id, t1.t, time_to_sec(t1.t) s
from times t1
left join times t2 on t1.id = t2.id
  and time_to_sec(t1.t) > time_to_sec(t2.t)
  and abs(time_to_sec(t1.t) - time_to_sec(t2.t)) <= 20
where t2.id is null
group by t1.t, t1.id
```

uses "groupwise-max" method with dynamicaly defined group. Seems to work on your testing data.

Comment: Thank you @user1786423 very much for working on my problem! I will test it, but for the first time it looks good. I will integrate to my code and i will inform you. Thank you again!!!

Comment: is there any possibility to have counters on the same ids? I mean:
    id    time          counter
    1     13:00:01  1,
    2     13:00:09  1,
    1     13:00.23  2,
    2     13:00:11  2,

Comment: There would be probably a way to do it, something along http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql (would need to order by id first and time second for ranking, then maybe as needed). But I strongly suggest doing it in application.